Are the arrows in commutative diagram always morphisms?
During my learning algebra, commuting diagrams are frequently used in many books, but I found sometimes that the authors do not specify whether the arrows are homomorphisms or just maps.
For instance, in the question of proving the Five Lemma, the authors just say that in the following commutative diagram of Abelian groups, each row is exact and $\alpha,\beta,\delta,\eta$ are isomorphisms, and ask me to show that $\gamma$ is also an isomorphism.
$$
\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
A @>{}>> B @>{}>> C @>{}>> D @>{}>> E\\
@V\alpha VV @V\beta VV @V\gamma VV @V\delta VV @V\eta VV\\
A' @>{}>> B' @>{}>> C' @>{}>> D' @>{}>> E'
\end{CD}
$$
My doubt is that whether the proposition "$\gamma$ is a homomorphism" should be proved or it is a given condition from the words "commutative diagram"?
From what I understand, in a commutative diagram $\Gamma$, if two objects $A$ and $B$ are in the same category $\mathcal{C}$, then the arrow $A\longrightarrow B$ is in $\mathbf{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A,B)$ the set of morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$. Especially, if $\mathcal{C}=\mathsf{Set}$ then the arrows are just set maps; if $\mathcal{C}=\mathsf{Grp}$ then the arrows are group homomorphisms; if $\mathcal{C}=R\text{-}\mathsf{mod}$ then the arrows are $R$-module homomorphisms; etc.
By my thought above, consider the universal property of free groups: let $S$ be a set and let $G$ be a group, denote $F(S)$ the free group on $S$.
$$
\require{AMScd}\begin{CD} S @>>> F(S)\\ @.     {_{\rlap{}}\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(30deg)}{{\xrightarrow[\rule{3.52em}{0em}]{}}}} @VVV\\  @. G \end{CD}
$$
[1] the downrightarrow: $\overset{S}{\phantom{f}}\searrow\underset{G}{\phantom{f}}\in\mathbf{Hom}_{\mathsf{Set}}(S,G)$.
[2] the rightarrow: $S\rightarrow F(S)\in\mathbf{Hom}_{\mathsf{Set}}\big(F,F(S)\big)$.
[3] the down arrow: $\overset{F(S)}{\underset{G}{\downarrow}}\in\mathbf{Hom}_{\mathsf{Grp}}\big(F(S),G\big)$.
So I can use this to explain whether an arrow represents a homomorphism or not. Am I right?

"the authors do not specify whether the arrows are homomorphisms or just maps" Two things: (1) the words map and (homo)morphism are used interchangeably most of the time. In particular, map basically never refers to a bare function of sets (unless you're directly working with sets). In your five-lemma example, if the author talks about maps then they almost certainly mean "maps of abelian groups," i.e. group homomorphisms. (2) If you are handed a diagram of abelian groups, or in $\mathrm{Ab}$, this implies that all objects are abelian groups and all morphisms maps of abelian groups.

A diagram is a functor.

If you're given a "mixed" diagram, as in your free group example, it is pretty much expected of the author to state which morphisms belong to which category, unless it really is brilliantly clear from context. But these kinds of diagrams aren't all that common (your mileage may vary).

Your diagram for the universal property of groups is slightly imprecise. The more accurate version has two components living in two different categories; see the Wikipedia page for examples.

@NaïmFavier There's "diagrams as a technical tool" (i.e., functors) in category theory and there's "diagrams as we use them," both of which are closely related. As an instance of the latter the diagram is completely fine, and I don't think there's much use in hammering this into functor shape here :)

I disagree that it's completely fine: as I said, it's slightly imprecise because it lacks the information of what lives in what category and implicitly applies forgetful functors. For example, I would not use it when teaching universal properties, at least not initially, lest my students end up with doubts as illustrated by this question. If you're giving a presentation to working mathematicians who've seen this sort of stuff a billion times, sure, go for it.

It should be mentioned that an isomorphism is a homomorphism by definition, so assuming "isomorphism" is the wording the author used then they did indeed specify that $\gamma$ must be a homomorphism.

But a homomorphism in $\mathbf{Set}$ is just a function and an isomorphism in $\mathbf{Set}$ is just a bijection, so this still leaves the essential question of what category the diagram lies in (here, the category of abelian groups, so "isomorphism" indeed means "isomorphism of abelian groups").

Thanks for reminding me the general definition of universal property in category, I had read it long ago and I had forgotten it. Let me have a review.@NaïmFavier

My use of "map" refers to some map $f$ such that we may not have $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. I agree with your opinion that we should not draw the diagram about universal property as functors, just keep in mind what it looks like as functors. Thanks for your answering.@BenSteffan

“Your use of” “map” is a very idiosyncratic use; it’s best to avoid using words differently from how others use them.

Yes, I think so, but what is the exact meaning of "map"? I see somewhere even a not well-defined ($f(x)$ has several distinct values $y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n$ for some $x$) $f$ can be said to be a map. Is there a word can be descried a $f$ which is not well-defined?@KevinCarlson

Think of it like this: you need to have the definition of diagrams be the same for all kinds of categories, including ones where the objects are not sets and the morphisms are not functions between sets, hence it would make more sense to always ask diagrams to be comprised of objects and morphisms only.
This also lies in the naming process: if a diagram is called "diagram in the category $\mathcal{C}$", then that means that the vertices are objects of the category and the arrows are morphisms - in this case it is "diagram of Abelian groups" which implicitly means that it is a diagram in the category whose objects are Abelian groups and the arrows are morphisms of Abelian groups.
